# Can I have two templates (content.ftl) on Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

I am using GeoServer for creating two web map applications. Under the GeoServer data directory, I have changed the content.ftl files for the use of my first map application. Now I am building the second map app, and would like to apply a different template to it.

Is it possible to define different templates for the two map applications?

Comment: I think that each feature can have one (and only) one template. Could you copy the layer?

Comment: Yes, The two maps will be using different layers. The problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple templates in your data directory. They just need to be in separate directories.

Have a look at the [Template Lookup](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/freemarker.html#template-lookup)

> Geoserver looks up templates in three different places, allowing for
>   various level of customization. For example given the content.ftl
>   template used to generate WMS GetFeatureInfo content:

```
 - Look into GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/<workspace>/<datastore>/<featuretype>/content.ftl to see if there is a feature type specific template
 - Look into GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/<workspace>/<datastore>/content.ftl to see if there is a store specific template
 - Look into GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/<workspace>/content.ftl to see if there is a workspace specific template
 - Look into GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/content.ftl looking for a global override
 - Look into GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/templates/content.ftl looking for a global override
 - Look into the GeoServer classpath and load the default template
```

So You could have two workspaces, one for each webgis, and then place the appropriate template in the correct workspace folder.